# Value of function parameter is not getting

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm not getting the actual value of my parameter `name` in the below function. Object.assign taking the function parameter `name` as a string literal so the resulted JSON object also named as `name`

see the below code.

[image]

Please see the resulted json object i got.

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it with `[]`

```
return Object.assign(..., {[name]: JSON.parse(...)})
```